# Django Test Creating Forms with New IDs

Tags: python, django

I have just moved all of my AJAX validation code over to Django Forms. I need some help updating my tests.  I basically have some test data, declared as constants, that are used across all suites. I am then this data repeatedly throughout my tests.

As part of the setup I create some users and login the user that I need:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    create_user(username='staff', email='staff@staff.com',
                password='staff', staff=True)
    create_user(username='agent', email='agent@agent.com',
                password='agent', staff=False)
    ShiftType.objects.create(type_id='SI', description='Sales Inbox')
    self.client.login(username='staff', password='staff')
```

The tear down deletes this data (or it used to):

```
def tearDown(self):
    # Clean up the DB
    self.client.logout()
    ShiftType.objects.all().delete()
    User.objects.all().delete()
    Event.objects.all().delete()
    RecurrentEvent.objects.all().delete()
```

This was working fine, but now the form does not validate because the form value id given by the users is incremented each time. For example:

```
 ERROR: <ul class="errorlist"><li>employee_id<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Printing the form allows me to see that the ids are being incremented each time.

Why is this happening even though I am deleting all employees?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using text fixtures rather than creating and deleting the data every time. This is pretty easy to do in Django. In your tests.py it would look something like this

```
class BlogTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['core/fixtures/test.json']
```

When you do this django will build you a test database, load the fixture into it, run your tests, and then blow away the database after the tests are done. If you want to even use a different database engine (we do this to have our tests use sqlite because it is fast) you can throw something like this into your settings.py

This will make it so the ID's are the same every single time which would fix your problem.